# How to select and interpret Goodness of fit test for an epidemiological study with small sample size?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, small-sample

I have a study that found an association between exposure to antidepressants and the risk of preeclampsia.

The number of women who were exposed and had an outcome (i.e. preeclampsia) was small:
10 cases with preeclampsia  / 210 exposed women.

Generalized Linear Models with binomial distribution and log function was used to calculate the relative risk (SPSS software). The reviewer asked us to “report the model goodness of fit criteria (to ensure correct specification of the model)”.

How should I reply him? Because our study is an exploratory study that suggested an association, we are not predicting anything. Besides, the number of exposed cases were too small. Thank you so much.

Comment: At first sight, it does seem to be a strange request from the referee. Can you say more? Does your model just have exposure to antidepressant yes/no as a precictor? I assume that preclampsia yes/no is the outcome. If that is so it can be represented by a 2x2 table. What's missing in that case is the number of cases of pre-eclampsia out of women who are not exposed.

Comment: We examined the use of antidepressants (yes/no) and adjusted for these following covariates: age at delivery (categorized into <=19;20-29; 30-34;>=35), ethnicity (white, non-white), alcohol consumption (yes/no), smoking during pregnancy (yes/no) , any endocrine disorders (yes/no)  and concurrent use of vasoconstrictors (yes/no) . And yes, preeclampsia (yes/no) is the outcome. In the unexposed group, we have 95,376 women and 2,582 preeclampsia cases (2.7%). Please help me :)

Comment: The request is a reasonable one, even for an exploratory study.  But if you can substantiate that the "number of exposed cases was too small" to assess goodness of fit, then that should suffice.  Often the simplest way to make such a demonstration is to conduct a suitable goodness of fit test and show the p-value is high.

Comment: Please show me how to do that, because I only have basic statistical skill.. In the Generalized Linear Model of SPSS, it showed the Goodness of fit tables with Value, df and Value/df as in this respective order: Deviance (68.215; 94; 0.726); Scaled Deviance (68.215; 94); Pearson Chi-Square (123.855; 94; 1.318); Scaled Pearson Chi-Square (123.855; 94) ; Log Likelihood (-116.854); Akaike's Information Criterion (255.707); Finite Sample Corrected AIC (AICC 255.710); Bayesian Information Criterion (359.853) and Consistent AIC (370.853). For some, the df and Value/df are not available.

Comment: Those statistics tell you almost nothing about goodness of fit.  Typically, GoF is assessed by including one or more additional explanatory variables in the model derived from the original ones: examples include quadratic and logarithmic terms. If these significantly improve the model, then you conclude the original one does not fit very well; otherwise, you have *some* evidence that the original one might be reasonable.  There are many graphical GoF methods, too, often based on standard model diagnostic plots.